# Build URL from Form Fields with Javascript or jquery - Reg

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, paypal

Build URL from Form Fields with Javascript or jquery

I need to make external link using a form with a variable like below

https://www.paypal.me/BusinessName/2500inr (Where 2500 should be a variable)

The resulting URL will be shown in the "url" named field. if the user clicks on that it should popup in an external browser widow.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

`<a id="someLink" target="_blank">Click me</a>`

jQuery:

```
var x = $('#fieldId').val();
var src = 'https://www.paypal.me/BusinessName/'+ x +'inr';
```

$('#someLink').attr('href', src);

Now don't you expect me write a form for you.